# Как начать использовать Canvas в Gwt-приложении?

Tags: gwt

Как начать использовать Canvas в Gwt-приложении?

Comment: Вот есть неплохой туториал [Статья на эту тему](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/05/gwt-and-html5-canvas-demo.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теперь использовать Canvas в Gwt-приложении [гораздо проще](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/doc/latest/ReleaseNotes.html#HTML5).

Comment: Тут такое дело... ссылка, ответ, ну вы понимаете ))

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно вас понял, то на сегодняшний день существует две библиотеки, которые позволяют использовать Canvas в GWT:

[GWTCanvas](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/GWTCanvas)

[gwt-canvas](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-canvas/)